# How to formulate $\sum_{ij} w_{ij}x_i^\top x_j$ in more compressed form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, graph-laplacian

I know that the following is true:
$$1/2\sum_{ij} w_{ij}\|x_i-x_j \|_2^2=tr(XLX^\top)$$
where $L=D-W$ is the laplacian matrix of $W$, and $D$ is the degree matrix of $W$.

However i like to know if we can do something similar for the following as well:
$$\sum_{ij} w_{ij}x_i^\top x_j$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, $w_{ij}$ is supposed to be an entry of $L$, and $x_i$ a column of $X$.  If that's the case, we can rewrite
$$
\sum_{ij} w_{ij} x_i^Tx_j = \sum_{ij} [L]_{ij}[X^TX]_{ij} = 
\operatorname{tr}(LX^TX) = \operatorname{tr}(XLX^T)
$$
so, it seems that the right side of your equation is actually the condensed form of the sum you've just written.